# Docker change a port publishing of a running container

Tags: docker, port

I created a running container:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                              NAMES
d7b65971bbb9        gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest   "/assets/wrapper"   3 days ago          Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8083->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8082->80/tcp   gitlab
```

And I want to change the published port `0.0.0.0:8082->80/tcp` to `0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp`

The container has changed from the original, so I don't want to delete and create a new container, just change the port. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker change published ports on live container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032042/docker-change-published-ports-on-live-container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Best pratice: immutable images

The best practice of docker assume that an image is immutable. Hence you should write a `Dockerfile` from the image `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest` with the changes operated to the container.

#### Changing published port of running container

Sorry to bear the bad news. You cannot.

#### Bonus: ssh?

Adding ssh to a container is a really **really** bad idea! [Jpetazzo, Docker engineer, explains why](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/).

Comment: A workaround: `docker stop <id>; docker commit your-container-name local-image-name; docker rm <id>;docker run -d -p 5001:5000 --name your-container-name local-image-name`. This is not recommended but may help troubleshoot application issues.