# Pass arguments/Add mapping to a running docker container

Tags: docker

I am new to docker.
I spun a docker container using the command `docker run  jenkins/jenkins:lts`. This command also contained a few mappings - `-p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000` and others.

Is there way to add another mapping to this container without using the `docker run` command and without knowing what the original arguments were used with `docker run`.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker change published ports on live container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032042/docker-change-published-ports-on-live-container)

Comment: In short, `docker rm` the container and start over.  Note that this is extremely routine (you also need to do it if there’s a new image, for example, maybe with a critical security fix) and you need to write down the `docker run` command in a script, or use a tool like Docker Compose that manages it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use docker entry point, which give you best way to manage input to docker container runtime.